# iOS: Write to file fails in AppStore app version

Tags: ios, file-io

I have an app that opens a file using

```
theHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
```

and then writes some data to it using

```
[theHandle writeData:data];
```

In the AppStore version writing to file fails if the phone has Passcode activated and the phone is locked when writing occurs. In development environment everything works just fine.

What is the cause for such a behavior and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I feel like I remember reading that iOS locks the disk with the passcode while locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Store version of the app had Data Protection enabled so the files were locked by the OS as soon as the passcode was activated.

**EDIT:** so far the only solution seems to be make your app ready for such a use case, keeping the data elsewhere (User Defaults for example) and write to files only when the phone is unlocked.

Comment: that's an answer for the first part of the question. still looking for the second one